Leaflet map with Flutter, filled polygon
I am trying to display a filled polygon.
The polygon draws, but does not fill.
This is my widget code, and from I have read, the color property should fill the polygon, but it doesn't.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';

class MapTest extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final points = [
      LatLng(51.506522814441, -0.17111533337402),
      LatLng(51.50674394161174, -0.1664646204108733),
      LatLng(51.50650353768864, -0.15824633198924243),
      LatLng(51.501080756682505, -0.15792446690745532),
      LatLng(51.49982514395529, -0.16506987172312915),
      LatLng(51.501615049478445, -0.1740177209968108),
      LatLng(51.505007662555826, -0.17438250142283618),
      LatLng(51.50647682606331, -0.17388897496409594),
      LatLng(51.506522814441, -0.17111533337402)
    ];

    return FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
        initialCenter: LatLng(51.503363, -0.167030),
        initialZoom: 15.0,
      ),
      children: [
        TileLayer(
          urlTemplate: "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",          
        ),
        PolygonLayer(
          polygons: [
            Polygon(
              points: points,
              color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
              borderStrokeWidth: 3.0,
              borderColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Thank you

Issue might be a cause of missing isFilled boolean property (https://docs.fleaflet.dev/layers/polygon-layer) although it seems to be deprecated for Polygon (https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_map/latest/flutter_map/Polygon/isFilled.html)
